# React Native crashes during app:processDebugManifest

Tags: android, react-native

I had to delete and reinstall my `node-modules` file to correct a different issue, and I reinstalled my modules using the `yarn install` command. When I did, I got the crash

```
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:24:3-97:17 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:24:3-97:17 to override.
```

I tried the suggested fix of trying to add the 'tools:replace' line into my manifest, including the appropriate xmlns url. I also tried relinking my modules to android studio.

Here's the relevant section of my app file.

```
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kalleonative"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
... 
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase-analytics')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1') {
        force = true
    }
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.46.4"  // From node_module
    compile 'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.0-beta14'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.4.0-beta1'
    compile project(':react-native-immediate-phone-call')
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this crash.

Comment: Have you tried adding this to your gradle.properties  android.enableJetifier=true

    android.useAndroidX=true

Comment: Are you using React-native 0.60?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the dependency conflicts Add these two lines in your gradle.properties file Hope it will solve the issue

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```